# How to remove ugly row in pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so I am filling dataframes from 2 different files. While those 2 files should have the same structure (the values should be different thought) the resulting dataframes look different. So when printing those I get:

```
                a              b              c        d
0        70402.14   70370.602112       0.533332       98
1        31362.21   31085.682726       1.912552      301       
...           ...            ...            ...      ...
753919   64527.16   64510.008206       0.255541       71
753920   58077.61   58030.943621       0.835758      152

                a              b              c        d
index
0       118535.32  118480.657338       0.280282       47
1        49536.10   49372.999416       0.429902       86
...           ...            ...            ...      ...
753970   52112.95   52104.717927       0.356051      116
753971   37044.40   36915.264944       0.597472      165
```

So in the second dataframe there is that "index" row that doesnt make any sense for me and it causes troubles in my following code. I did neither write the code to fill the files into the dataframes nor I did create those files. So I am rather interested in checking if such a row exists and how I might be able to remove it. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just the way the df is being printed so its truncating the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second dataframe has an index level named "index".
You can remove the name with

```
df.index.name = None
```

---

For example,

```
In [126]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3))    

In [128]: df.index.name = 'index'

In [129]: df
Out[129]: 
        0   1   2
index            
0       0   1   2
1       3   4   5
2       6   7   8
3       9  10  11
4      12  13  14

In [130]: df.index.name = None

In [131]: df
Out[131]: 
    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
```

---

The dataframe might have picked up the name "index" if you used `reset_index` and `set_index` like this:

```
In [138]: df.reset_index()
Out[138]: 
   index   0   1   2
0      0   0   1   2
1      1   3   4   5
2      2   6   7   8
3      3   9  10  11
4      4  12  13  14

In [140]: df.reset_index().set_index('index')
Out[140]: 
        0   1   2
index            
0       0   1   2
1       3   4   5
2       6   7   8
3       9  10  11
4      12  13  14
```

Answer (score 0):

Index is just the first column - it's numbering the rows by default, but you can change it a number of ways (e.g. filling it with values from one of the columns)